# Is there a way to substr a value returned by toShortString()?

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I am working with openlayers and I can get a point on a map but I can't get the individual coords.

```
       feat = drawLayer.features[0];

       var geom = feat.geometry;
       var loca = geom.toShortString();
       var long = loc.substr(0,9);

       alert(geom.toShortString());//returns the correct coords in xx.xxx,xx.xxx format
       alert(loca);//returns 2 very large numbers in xx.xxx,xx.xxx format
       alert(long);//returns the first, incorrect number
```

What exaclty am I doing wrong and how can I correct it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't use the `toShortString()` method to get the individual coordinates of a geometry. It is just a convenience function to get a string describing the LonLat object (i.e "coordX, coordY").

Use the `x` and `y` properties instead:

```
var geom = feat.geometry;
var lon = geom.x;  //X coordinate / Longitude
var lat = geom.y;   //Y coordinte / Latitude
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var parts = geom.toShortString().split(',');
var long = parts[0];
var lat = parts[1];
```